# Reading linked list from binary file (C Programming: A Modern Approach, programming project 22.10)

Tags: c, linked-list, fwrite, fread

could you help me?

Here is the whole program: http://knking.com/books/c2/programs/inventory2.c

I need to add dump and restore functions that will write (using fwrite) the linked list into the file or load it (using fread) from the file.

My take:

```
void dump(void)
{
  FILE *fp;
  char output_file[30];
  int i;

  printf("Enter name of input file: ");
  scanf("%s", &output_file);

  if ((fp = fopen(output_file, "wb")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", output_file);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (inventory != NULL) {
    fwrite(&inventory->number, sizeof(inventory->number), 1, fp);
    fwrite(inventory->name, strlen(inventory->name) + 1, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&inventory->on_hand, sizeof(inventory->on_hand), 1, fp);

    inventory = inventory->next;
  }

  fclose(fp);
}

void restore(void)
{
  FILE *fp;
  char input_file[30];
  int i = 0;

  printf("Enter name of output file: ");
  scanf("%s", &input_file);

  if ((fp = fopen(input_file, "rb")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", input_file);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  inventory = malloc(sizeof(struct part));
  fread(&inventory->number, sizeof(inventory->number), 1, fp);
  fread(&inventory->name[i], sizeof(inventory->name), 1, fp);
  fread(&inventory->on_hand, sizeof(inventory->on_hand), 1, fp);

  fclose(fp);
}
```

Restore function keeps crashing. It also keeps reading 26 characters to inventory->name causing inventory->on_hand showing wrong values. I also have no idea how to load the rest of linked list.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &output_file);` and `scanf("%s", &input_file);`  invokes *undefined behavior*: `%s` calls for `char*`, but what is passed is `char(*)[30]`.

Comment: Using global variables and assignment in conditions is a "modern approach"? In the early 70s maybe...

Comment: In `dump()`, you write `strlen(inventory->name) + 1` bytes, but in `restore()` you read in `sizeof(inventory->name)` bytes.  The two aren't necessarily equal.

Comment: Yes, that's why it's loading 26 characters from file even when there is only few, but I don't know how to check length of inventory->name that's in file before loading it.

Comment: @M.Chelm Why not just write `sizeof(inventory->name)` bytes to the file? You might want to zero the unused bytes after the null terminator in `inventory->name` first to avoid writing junk to the file. Alternatively, write zero-valued bytes to the file to fill up the remaining part of the 26-byte field.